# Change kernel on Ubuntu Server 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel

How may i change kernel on headless Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 64bit ? I want to try some dailybuilt kernels because current one includes grsec patches which cause segfault problems. Or even same kernel without grsec.

The current one

```
Linux ovh-tb 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 7 11:35:27 CET 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/706519/kernel-panic-at-boot-please-help/707042#707042

Comment: @ DnrDevil, thanks but i followed another topic, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully did that procedure on production server.
It is safe to update or change kernel by installing meta package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

But then you need change grub entry to use new kernel, so
check current menuentries issue:

```
grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Edit /etc/default/grub as root then update GRUB_DEFAULT to the corresponding menuentry number. Remember that entries started from "0"

```
sudo update-grub
```

Related topics:

[How can I use Kernel 3.19 in 14.04 now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598483/how-can-i-use-kernel-3-19-in-14-04-now)

[How to switch to a generic kernel in a headless Ubuntu Server 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226087/how-to-switch-to-a-generic-kernel-in-a-headless-ubuntu-server-12-04)